# How to customize onEdit() script to work on all rows modified when a list of values is pasted from the clipboard?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I believe different variations of this has been posted but cant seem to make it work for my onEdit. The script I have is for dynamic dropdown list depending on what is edited in column 1. The problem I'm running into is that when I paste batch of data into column 1, it only edits applies the onEdit to the first adjacent cell. Relatively new to Appscript so unsure so my attempts of editing this have been unsuccessful. Appreciate any help!

What I have so far:

```
 function onEdit(e){
    var activeCell = e.range;
    var val = activeCell.getValue();
    var r = activeCell.getRow();
    var c = activeCell.getColumn();
    var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
    if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1){
      applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
    } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 1){
      applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
    } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === thirdLevelColumn && r > 1){
      applyThirdLevelValidation(val,r);
    }

 }//end onEdit
```

Comment: You say you are pasting a range of values, and yet in your script the variable is called `activeCell` which would imply that its only 1 value. Can you put a `console.log(e.range.getValues())` as the first line to see what is actually being returned?

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply! Maybe I'm not placing it in the correct place or format but I couldn't get it to work. Here is a link to the doc with the whole script not just the OnEdit. Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tNvPvGhm5ctqz1lcp-TnGMqihNaLg_PDtZPIqZQJOls/edit#gid=0

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you want to use the sheet? You want to select a value from the dropdown or paste a set of values? Maybe include a mock up of the desired use so that I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
const action = [
  applyFirstLevelValidation,
  applySecondLevelValidation,
  applyThirdLevelValidation,
];

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== mainWsName
    || e.range.rowEnd <= (sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1)) {
    return;
  }
  e.range.getValues()
    .forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
      const rowNumber = e.range.rowStart + rowIndex;
      row.forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
        const columnNumber = e.range.columnStart + columnIndex;
        action[columnNumber - 1](value, rowNumber);
      });
    });
}
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thank you for all these resources and thank you for your reply! I wasn't able to get it work, any chance you can take a look at the whole script and let me know what I'm doing wrong? Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tNvPvGhm5ctqz1lcp-TnGMqihNaLg_PDtZPIqZQJOls/edit#gid=0

Comment: OK — `firstLevelColumn` and friends simply represent column _numbers_. Edited the answer to make the code work. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

`getValue()` returns the value to the first cell, to get the values of all the range cells, use `getValues()` instead.

Here is one way to use `getValues()` doing minimal changes to the original function:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  e.range.getValues().forEach((row, i) => {
      var r = i + 1;
      row.forEach((val, j) => {
          var c = j + 1;
          if (wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1) {
            applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r);
          } else if (wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 1) {
            applySecondLevelValidation(val, r);
          } else if (wsName === mainWsName && c === thirdLevelColumn && r > 1) {
            applyThirdLevelValidation(val, r);
          }
        }
      });
  });
} //end onEdit
```