# Re-triggering onEdit for each row when pasting multiple rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'll start by saying that I'm a complete novice but I spent a few hours manipulating a bit of code I found online to fit a sheet I'm designing. I'm attempting to create a script that will generate a dynamic dropdown to the right of a cell when a value is selected from an existing dropdown.

```js
function onEdit(event){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lists")

  var r = event.range;
  
  if(r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getRow() > 1 && ss.getName() == "Main"){
    
    r.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
   
    var types = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1,  datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    var typeIndex = types[0].indexOf(r.getValue()) + 1;
    
    if(typeIndex != 0) {
    
    var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, typeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    r.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
      
    }
  
  }

}
```

Here's my process so far:

1. I created the initial script with `var r = ss.getActiveCell()`, which worked for a single cell at a time, but I need it to work when multiple rows are pasted. [Version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af3Dk.png)
2. I edited to `var r = event.range`, which successfully applied the script to all rows that were pasted. However, the script only generated the list for the top cell that I pasted and created that same list for all pasted cells. [Version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx0D4.png)

What I need is for onEdit to essentially re-trigger for each row when data is pasted in. [Goal Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHLES.png)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-triggering onEdit make it to be able to handle both cases. For this, you could take advantage of `Range.getRows()`, `Range.getColumns()` as well of edit event object properties like (in this answer `e` is the event object):

- e.range.rowStart
- e.range.rowEnd
- e.range.columnStart
- e.range.columnEnd

If a single cell was edited, `rowStart` and `rowEnd` will have the same value, the same for `columnStart` and `columnEnd`.

i.e. you might replace

```
r.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
```

by (remember, I'm using `e` instead of `event` for the event object)

```
r.offset(0, 1, e.range.getRows()).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
```

Related

- [Google script onEdit in all pasted cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45755440/1595451)
- [How to customize onEdit() script to work on all rows modified when a list of values is pasted from the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68221172/1595451)